# Optimizing NSNumber numberWithInt:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, nsnumber

I am profiling an iPhone app and I noticed a strange pattern. In a certain block of code that's called quite frequently...

```
    [item setQuadrant:[NSNumber numberWithInt:a]];
    [item setIndex:[NSNumber numberWithInt:b]];
    [item setTimestamp:[NSNumber numberWithInt:c]];
    [item setState:[NSNumber numberWithInt:d]];
    [item setCompletionPercentage:[NSNumber numberWithInt:e]];
    [item setId_:[NSNumber numberWithInt:f]];
```

...the first call to [NSNumber numberWithInt:] takes an inordinate amount of time, in the order of 10-15x that of the remaining calls. I've verified that the results are consistent if I shuffle the lines (the first line is always the slow one, by the same ratio). Is there something going on that I'm not aware of?

Perhaps this happens because this block is inside a try/catch?

Comment: Does the first call take longer every time that is run, or just the first time after starting the app? The first time a method is called on a class will take longer because the runtime has to search for the implementation, but it caches it for the future.

Comment: You also might want to consider just using int rather than NSNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, NSNumber performs some code in it's `+load` implementation, which slows down the initial call to the class. Also note that `NSNumber` caches it's return value, so future calls to `+numberWithInt:` with the same value are faster than before, that could possibly be part of the issue.

Comment: Indeed, `NSNumber` keeps some kind of cache of instances representing low-value integers; setting up that cache may very well be what it's doing, but I think you mean `+initialize` rather than `+load`. That's the one that's sent before the class receives its first message.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the right answer based on other documents online. Low values are indeed cached, although this is not documented in the official API. Some people report higher retainCount than expected for low integer values, which is consistent with this timing issue.

Comment: i just posted another answer.. considering NSNumber is actually a wrapper for CFNumber, it is subject to CFNumber's optimizations and limitations - and it is set up long before @Riviera's code runs as part of the runtime setup or during `UIApplicationMain()` so `+load` is extremely unlikely to be the cause of the performance difference, considering it @Riviera says this block is called "frequently" - meaning it is always slower and not just the first time (instruments calculates the average).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the first value is much larger? apart from CoreFoundation's CFNumber caching, the "new" runtime uses tagged pointers, allowing integers within the range of 24 bit to be encoded directly into the pointer - the runtime then figure out it's a tagged pointer by looking at the last bit (and that its a CFNumber by looking at the 3 bits before the last bit and the target number size - 8, 16, 32, 64 bit - using the next 4 bits before).

On a 32-bit system (current iPhones), that means that for ("small") negative 32 bit numbers or large positive numbers, CoreFoundation will allocate an object. For everything else, it uses the following expression that is way faster:

```
    case kCFNumberSInt32Type: {
            int32_t value = *(int32_t *)valuePtr; // this loads the actual numerical value passed to CFNumberCreate()
#if !__LP64__
            // We don't bother allowing the min 24-bit integer -2^23 to also be fast-pathed;
            // tell anybody that complains about that to go ... hang.
            int32_t limit = (1L << 23);
            if (value <= -limit || limit <= value) break;
#endif
            uintptr_t ptr_val = ((uintptr_t)((intptr_t)value << 8) | (2 << 6) | kCFTaggedObjectID_Integer);
            return (CFNumberRef)ptr_val;
        }
```

(note that `!__LP64__` is true for 32-bit systems)

Taken from: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/CFNumber.c

Also, there is a caching mechanism that prevents a range of numbers from being re-created multiple times, just search for "__CFNumberCache" in the same source file.

Comment: That was not the scenario at the time of the question being asked. Tagged integers were added in iOS 6 and Mac OSX Lion, thus not an issue in the situation given.

Comment: we shouldn't make this a personal discussion. i just wanted to add it to this "old" question - according to my information tagged pointers were added to the runtime along with the support for weak references in iOS 5.